Using XPath with Python's lxml module, how to validate a node's path?
I'm using XPath with Python's lxml module, and have the following xml code.
<library>
  <section1>
    <book>
      <title>Harry Potter</title>
      <author>J.K. Rowling</author>
    </book>
  </section1>
  <section2>
    <book>
      <title>Sapiens</title>
      <author>Yuval Noah Harari</author>
    </book>
  </section2>
</library>

Now I have some title nodes: titles = root.xpath('//title'). How to validate if a title is a descendant of the child node section1 of the root of the xml? For some reason I have to get the titles first with //title, then do the validation, rather than find them directly by their full xml paths. The validation code should be like this:
titles = root.xpath('//title')
if title.xpath('.[ancestor::/library/section1]'):
    do_sth()

The above code results in a XPathEvalError: Invalid expression.

maybe first find section1 and later search title in this section1 - or use this //library/section1//title

I only want to keep titles that are descendants ... What do you mean by "keep"?
Do you mean you want to find only those titles, or do you mean you want to edit the document so that only those titles remain?

@John Gordon I meant I want to filter and pick those titles. I have some titles, some under section1 (which must be at a certain hierarchy in the XML), some under section2. I only want to keep those under section1.

@furas For some reason, I can't. The question is simplified scenario of a much more complex one.

.[ancestor::/library/section1] is obviously syntactically wrong. And .[predicateExpression] will only work in XPath 2 and later so you would need saxonche or elementpath for that with Python. In XPath 1 you can use self::node()[predicateExpression].

if you want to work only with section1 then it seems strange why you don't want to use //library/section1//title for this.

As for your attempt to write a relative XPath, in XPath 1.0 (which lxml supports), you can use e.g.
from lxml import etree as ET

root = ET.parse('librarySample1.xml')

titles = root.xpath('//title')

for title in titles:
    if title.xpath('self::node()[ancestor::section1/parent::library]'):
        print(title)

Or switch to the current version of XPath, XPath 3.1 by using saxonche where you can use e.g.
from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor

with PySaxonProcessor() as saxon_proc:
    xpath_proc = saxon_proc.new_xpath_processor()

    xpath_proc.set_context(xdm_item=saxon_proc.parse_xml(xml_file_name='librarySample1.xml'))

    titles = xpath_proc.evaluate('//title')

    for title in titles:
        xpath_proc.set_context(xdm_item=title)
        if xpath_proc.evaluate_single('.[ancestor::section1/parent::library]'):
            print(title)


Since <library> is the root, everything in the file is a descendant of <library>, so there's no point testing for it. Other than that, if you are looking for a <title> that is descendant of <section1> try:
from lxml import etree
books = """[your xml above]"""
doc = etree.XML(books)
for title in doc.xpath('//title[ancestor::section1]'):
    print(title.text)

Output in this case should be
Harry Potter


And to add the check that the section1 is a child of the library node (only necessary if your input is more complex than what you have shown), do `'//title[ancestor::section1/parent::library]'

@Michael Kay How to do the same with relative path? .[ancestor::section1/parent::library] seems invalid.

The reason I test for <library> is to make sure a existing title's ancestor section1 is the child of the root.

XPath 1.0 has a silly restriction that you can't use a predicate after ".". It's about 20 years since I've used XPath 1.0, but IIRC you can write (.)[predicate] to get around it; alternatively use self::node()[predicate].
